# GULP append text to a placeholder location

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I have a list of dependencies that I want to append to the injection location in my app.js. Is there a gulp plugin that will allow me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gulp plugin for injecting javascript and stylesheets.
Check this out. Its well documented also.
[Gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject)

hope it helps.

Comment: This will work perfectly I didnt see this on my lookout.